# Not able to connect to Rds Postgres instance when created from Github action

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, github-actions, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-cdk

When i am deploying a Postgres instance using Terraform CDKTF from my local machine, i am able to connect to it after it's creation from my machine, but when i use same code to deploy the Postgres instance from Github actions, i am not able to connect to the deployed instance:

Here's my code:

```
public PostgresStack(final Construct scope, final String id) {
        super(scope, id);
        final String REGION = "eu-central-1";
        final String TAG_NAME = "Name";
        final String TAG_CREATED_BY = "Created By";

        AwsProvider awsProvider = AwsProvider.Builder.create(this, "AWS")
                .region(REGION)
                .defaultTags(List.of(AwsProviderDefaultTags.builder()
                        .tags(Collections.singletonMap(TAG_CREATED_BY, "CDKTF"))
                        .build()))
                .build();

        Vpc vpc = Vpc.Builder.create(this, "postgres_vpc")
                .cidrBlock("10.0.0.0/16")
                .enableDnsSupport(true) // This is needed to support both DNS resolution, DNS hostnames
                .enableDnsHostnames(true)
                .build();

        SecurityGroupIngress securityGroupIngress = SecurityGroupIngress.builder()
                .fromPort(5432)
                .toPort(5432)
                .protocol("tcp")
                .cidrBlocks(List.of("0.0.0.0/0"))
                .build();

        SecurityGroupEgress securityGroupEgress = SecurityGroupEgress.builder()
                .fromPort(0)
                .toPort(0)
                .protocol("tcp")
                .cidrBlocks(List.of("0.0.0.0/0"))
                .build();

        // Create a security group that allows inbound traffic on port 5432 using Ingress (postgres default port) from any IP address.
        SecurityGroup securityGroup = SecurityGroup.Builder.create(this, "postgres_sg")
                .namePrefix("postgres-sg-")
                .vpcId(vpc.getId())
                .ingress(List.of(securityGroupIngress))
                .egress(List.of(securityGroupEgress))
                .tags(Collections.singletonMap(TAG_NAME, "postgres-sg"))
                .build();

        // Subnet 1 (Private as there is no internet gateway associated with it)
        Subnet privateSubnet = Subnet.Builder.create(this, "postgres_private_subnet")
                .vpcId(vpc.getId())
                .cidrBlock("10.0.2.0/24")
                .availabilityZone(REGION + "a")
                .tags(Collections.singletonMap(TAG_NAME,"postgres_private_subnet"))
                .dependsOn(List.of(vpc))
                .build();

        // Subnet 2 (Public as there is an internet gateway associated with it)
        Subnet publicSubnet = Subnet.Builder.create(this, "postgres_public_subnet")
                .vpcId(vpc.getId())
                .cidrBlock("10.0.1.0/24")
                .availabilityZone(REGION + "b")
                // By attaching an internet gateway to the VPC and creating a public subnet with map_public_ip_on_launch set to true,
                // the resources using this subnet will be publicly accessible.
                .mapPublicIpOnLaunch(true)
                .tags(Collections.singletonMap(TAG_NAME,"postgres_public_subnet"))
                .dependsOn(List.of(vpc))
                .build();

        // Internet Gateway to access resources from publicly exposed subnets
        InternetGateway internetGateway = InternetGateway.Builder.create(this, "postgres_internet_gateway")
                .vpcId(vpc.getId())
                .tags(Collections.singletonMap(TAG_NAME, "postgres_internet_gateway"))
                .dependsOn(List.of(vpc))
                .build();

        RouteTableRoute route = new RouteTableRoute.Builder()
                .cidrBlock("0.0.0.0/0")
                .gatewayId(internetGateway.getId())
                .build();

        // AWS Route Table to update default route to our internet gateway
        RouteTable routeTable = RouteTable.Builder.create(this, "postgres_public_route_table")
                .vpcId(vpc.getId())
                .route(List.of(route))
                .tags(Collections.singletonMap(TAG_NAME, "postgres_public_route_table"))
                .dependsOn(List.of(vpc))
                .build();

        // Public Subnet & Route Table Association
        RouteTableAssociation routeTableAssociation = RouteTableAssociation.Builder.create(this, "postgres_public_route_table_association")
                .subnetId(publicSubnet.getId())
                .routeTableId(routeTable.getId())
                .dependsOn(List.of(publicSubnet, routeTable))
                .build();

        final String DB_SUBNET_GROUP_NAME = "postgres_db_subnet_group";

        DbSubnetGroup dbSubnetGroup = DbSubnetGroup.Builder.create(this, DB_SUBNET_GROUP_NAME)
                .name(DB_SUBNET_GROUP_NAME)
                .subnetIds(List.of(privateSubnet.getId(), publicSubnet.getId()))
                .tags(Collections.singletonMap(TAG_NAME, DB_SUBNET_GROUP_NAME))
                .dependsOn(List.of(privateSubnet, publicSubnet))
                .build();

        //This object tells Terraform to Create a single AWS db instance of type postgres
        DbInstance rdsInstance = DbInstance.Builder.create(this, "MyRdsInstance")
                .allocatedStorage(20) //GB
                .dbName("my_terraform_cdktf_db")
                .username("my_terraform_cdktf_user")
                .password("my_terraform_cdktf_password")
                .engine("postgres")
                .engineVersion("15.2")
                .instanceClass("db.t3.micro")
                .port(5432)
                .dependsOn(List.of(dbSubnetGroup, securityGroup, vpc, routeTable, privateSubnet, publicSubnet, routeTable, routeTableAssociation))
                .dbSubnetGroupName(dbSubnetGroup.getName())
                .vpcSecurityGroupIds(List.of(securityGroup.getId()))
                .skipFinalSnapshot(true)
                .publiclyAccessible(true)
                .tags(Collections.singletonMap(TAG_NAME, "postgres_instance"))
                .build();

        // Output the connection details for the RDS instance
        TerraformOutput.Builder.create(this, "rds_endpoint")
                .value(rdsInstance.getEndpoint())
                .build();
    }
```

I am trying to connect the DB using
`nc -zv <db_endpoint> <db_port>`

Here's My VPC:
[image]

Comment: It seems you are using both public and private subnets in your DB subnet group, so it might be that in one case the RDS instance got deployed in the private subnet and in the second in the private.

Comment: I have only single instance

Comment: It doesn't matter, if you deploy one instance there is an equal chance of it getting deployed inside of a private or public subnet.

Comment: how to fix the issue?

Comment: Don't use the private subnet in the subnet group. What is a good practice is a different story altogether. It's a bad practice to deploy a DB in such a way that it's publicly accessible.